# How to use SupportMapFragment inside Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I know this question have many duplicate in Stackoverflow but when I use lib support 9.6.1 some function (as getMap) have been removed.

Basically I will call:

```
    ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map)).getMapAsync(this);
```

and implement OnMapReadyCallback interface for this Fragment.

However, If I have many Fragment put to and `R.id.container`. When I switch MapFragment by other fragment every thing must `recall => Map reload, data reload, ....`

It is a poor for practice. 
I don't want to redo, it make my application so bad performance.

Please show me a good solution to use the map.

Answer (score 2):

just use different Views as acontainers, and switch visibility between them. `view1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use to different containers -> Two different FrameLayouts with different id's.

In one of them keep only the map and hide the FrameLayout when you don't want to display it.

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```